# Asp.net + ajaxcontroltoolkit 4 + html editor extender + sanitizer

Tags: c#, webforms, ajaxcontroltoolkit, sanitization

OK, the problem is quite simple. I've successfully set up a html editor extender in my webforms 4 app. Everything works ok.

Reading the tuts further and finding a part, when they STRONGLY recommend to use a sanitizer, that ships with the ajaxcontroltoolkit 4. Great, I tell to myself. Set it up following the tutorial, everything works.

Well, almost everything - the formatting is gone after the submit. It seems the sanitizer strips EVERY tag, resulting in a situation, when my beloved html editor extender suddenly becomes a very standard textarea with fancy buttons.

So, I tried to disable sanitizer and check the output, if it is really that dangerous after inputting malicious script. The output was a standard html encoded text.

My question is - do I really need that so recommended sanitizer? Did I miss something? 
If yes, please, explain why do we need it and how to get it work.

P.S.: I believe I don't have to include the source code, because it is pretty much following the official tutorial on how to get it work. If you think different, tell me and I'll edit the post to include relevant parts here...

Edit:

Is the question not clear or why it has only 17 views? Give me a comment so I can improve it then...

Comment: You're not sanitizing the input as it's being saved, are you?  You only need to do so when displaying the data back out to the browser...  And also, there are functions like GetSafeHtmlFragment that allow you to retain safe Html, rather than htmlencode, which completely encodes the html.

Comment: @DavidStratton, right now I'm not doing anything. Set up the extender + sanitizer in web.config. Opened up my admin panel, inputted text, formatted it, submitted. When I tried to edit it again or review the result, the text isn't formatted at all. It just adds some <font>, but nothing else. Every other formatting is gone.

Comment: @DavidStratton, I'm not encoding the text in any way. I'm just using the extender with and without the recommended sanitizer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems this article describes pretty much the behavior I'm experiencing...

http://wpl.codeplex.com/workitem/17246

In other words, some weird bug and the only fix so far is to wait for the update/patch of the library... Or revert to the previous version.

Answer (score 0):

to solve this i logged in to my plesk account and changed "CAS trust level" to high (from medium) in asp.net settings page